# Title above DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

How should I design my `DataGridView` to have a title of DB table above it, and to dock both (title and `DataGridView`) into a container? I tried with `ToolStrip`, but they both dock in the left corner, and one covers another.

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that if you want a title for anything in WinForms then you use a `Label`. You can put the two in a user control and/or a `TableLayoutPanel` to help control the layout, depending on exactly what behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a `TableLayoutPanel` control with 1 column and 2 rows.

Dock(Top) the control you desire to work as title - `Label` for instance - or whatever you wish in first row, then set the row to autosize

Dock(Fill) the `DataGridView` in second row and set the row to percent (100%)

Set margins of both controls to (0;0;0;0) if you consider the gaps unsdesirable.

Place the `TableLayoutPanel` in your form the way you'd do with the single `DataGridView`

Comment: Thanks, i knew something easy can be done. However another option - Split container and you use of the panels for title - with label. thanks for help VBobCat !!